# Can I reclaim back my blood echoes after using the Hunter's mark?

Tags: bloodborne

I got stuck in a corner behind two bookcases in the Hunter's dream and I'm considering using the Hunter's mark to get out. Using the Hunter's mark will consume all my blood echoes.

Would I then be able to recover my blood echoes similarly to when you get killed or they will be lost forever?

Comment: Pretty sure they'll be gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will not be able to reclaim your Blood Echoes if you use the [Hunters Mark](http://bloodborne.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter%27s_Mark). The item description states:

> [...] a hunter loses all Blood Echoes [...]

BUT

If you have a [Bold Hunter's Mark](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Bold+Hunter%27s+Mark), you keep your Blood Echoes, but this item is consumed after use.

> [...] Without losing Blood Echoes [...]